# JsonSchema: Using type/format with binary data

Tags: jsonschema

I need a system to describe input and output data types.
A type can be a primitive type like "integer" or "string' or a custom type like "TensorFlow model" or "CSV table".
The validation properties I'm adding to the data validation properties that has big resemblance to the JsonSchema validation properties.

It might be nice to describe the input and output data types using the JsonSchema language.
What's the best way to do that?

I had something like this in mind:

```
{"inputs": {
  "model": {"type": "binary", "format": "TensorFlow model", "required": "true"},
  "rounds": {"type": "integer", "minimum": 1, "default": 100}
}}
```

P.S. I find the way `type` and `format` are used really confusing. Types are basic and general while formats are specific. My associations are the opposite. Usually you have many specialized types that can be expressed in one of the few formats.

Answer (score 1):

The primary aim of JSON Schema is to provide the format of JSON data.

The validation specification (draft-7) documents `format` in part as follows:

> Implementations MAY add custom format attributes.  Save for agreement
> between parties, schema authors SHALL NOT expect a peer
> implementation to support this keyword and/or custom format
> attributes.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-7.1

This means, you can add any format you want, but you can't expect it to work elsewhere. You should form agreements (or document what you mean) with anyone else that you expect to be able to use your schemas to validate the data you're providing.